# Removing elements that cut other elements using QGIS

Tags: remove, element, crossing

I have line elements and polgone-elements on two different layers (lets say layer A (line) and layer B (polygons). Now I want to remove all elements of layer A that crosses/touches/laying in polygones of layer B.

I tried the "difference"-function but this function only removes the part of the line laying in the polygon (and I want to remove the whole line).

Comment: Have you tried "Select by location"? Then edit and delete selected features

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! One day trying and the answer is so simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1. Select By Location
2. Then Edit and delete selected features